# How do I specifiy the last row of a list in a range as it grows?

Tags: excel

I have a list of items sold which grows longer with each sale. On a summary page I want to sum particular rows of a column.

Example:

Sheet1

```
  Person    Item    Amount

       1         5        6.00     This page has the knows the last column 
       1         7       10.50     by =counta($a2:$a20)+1 in cell f6
       2         5        6.00
       3         2       20.00
       3         9       16.00
       3         5        6.00
       4         1        2.50
```

Summary Page:

```
Person    Sales 
  1        =sumif(sales!$A$2:$A$8,$a2,sales!$C$1:$C$8) = 16.50
  2        =sumif(sales!$A$2:$A$8,$a3,sales!$C$1:$C$8) = 6.00
  3        =sumif(sales!$A$2:$A$8,$a4,sales!$C$1:$C$8) = 42.00
  4        =sumif(sales!$A$2:$A$8,$a5,sales!$C$1:$C$8) = 2.50
```

On one page I create an indirect reference by =concatenate("sales!$c$2:$c$",sales!$a$10) but that won't work on this one page. Is there another way?

Comment: You can use dynamic ranges: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=SUMIF(sales!A:A,A2,sales!C:C)
```

copied down to suit.

Answer (score 0):

I would use dynamic named ranges:

```
=SUMIF(Sales!People,A2,Sales!Amounts)
```

Here is an article on how to create dynamic named ranges:

http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html

Answer (score 0):

If this is really a "Table", in other words, you used the Insert Table method from the Insert Ribbon to set it up, then you can merely used structured references which will automatically expand as you add rows.

An equivalent of your formula, using structured references, and assuming you have renamed your table **SalesTbl**, might look like:

```
=SUMIF(SalesTbl[Person],$A2,SalesTbl[Amount])
```